# Отслеживание и копирование измененного файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

Используя модуль watchdog решил отслеживать раз в 10 секунд изменение файла с последующим копированием. Вот только копирование не происходит. Где я мог ошибиться?

```
# Подключение всех модулей
from watchdog.observers import Observer
import time
import shutil
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler


# Создаем класс наследник, через него может отслеживать изменения
class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        print("Файл был изменён. Копируем")
        shutil.copyfile(file_track, folder_dest)

# Файл что отслеживается
file_track = 'D:/CODING/Project/test.txt'
# Папка куда перемещать будем
folder_dest = 'D:/CODING/Project/result/test.txt'

# Запуск всего на отслеживание
handle = Handler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(handle, file_track, recursive=True)
observer.start()

# Программа будет срабатывать каждые 10 секунд
try:
    while(True):
        time.sleep(10)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()

observer.join()
```

Comment: 1) Т.е. `print("Файл был изменён. Копируем")` - печатается, а само копирование не проходит? (Вряд ли, учитывая п.2 далее). 2) А где вообще хоть раз вызывается `on_modified`?

Comment: Сообщение не выводится, файл не копируется. Не уверен, что событие on_modified корректно срабатывает, но не знаю как проверить.

Comment: На вопрос 2 ответьте. Понятия не имею об `observer`, но вы же не вызываете ни разу `on_modified`. Чисто теоретически могу предложить что-то вроде модификации первого параметра в `observer.schedule(handle.on_modified, file_track, recursive=True)` - синтаксис смотреть надо.

Comment: Разобрался. observer.schedule(handle, path=folder_track, recursive=False) отслеживаем состояние файлов в папке, а далее уже в def on_modified(self, event): используем условие на то, что был изменен конкретный файл if(event.src_path == file_track): Спасибо за напутствие и помощь.

Comment: Советую тогда исправленный код в ответ поместить.